# Topic design in a microservice architecture with eventing

Tags: microservices, azureservicebus

I am following a microservice architecture with eventing on `Azure Service Bus`. I need to publish events to a topic so a few microservices can process it.

I face three options. I can create just one topic and publish all sorts of events to that single topic. Or, I can create a topic for each event. Or, I can create a topic for each microservice.

My question is what is considered a best practice in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the same event can generally be published to multiple topics.  So you can publish an event to both an "every event from every service" firehose topic and an "every event from this service" topic.

In general, you want to think about, for any two disjoint types/categories of events, is there likely to be a consumer for which interest in type X suggests (read: weaker than a strong implication, more like a prediction worth staking a bet on if the payoff is acceptable) interest in type Y?  If that seems likely, then a topic consisting of the type Z (any event which is type X or type Y) is worth having.

In many cases, especially if events of a particular type are only emitted by one particular service and that service can make some ordering guarantees, it can be worth just having a topic for "every event from this service" and then have a consumer of that topic which remixes the messages into appropriate other topics.

Comment: Thank you @Levi Ramsey. I will follow the "every event from this service" pattern; that is, one topic per microservice, where only the owning microservice can publish events to that topic, and all other microservices can subscribe to it.